# Export from Oracle 10g database with 11g client

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11gr2, datapump

Database Version : 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0

Client Version: 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 (windows 7 64bit)

When I try to export (exp) a table from database:

```
exp usr/pass@remote_db file=f.dmp tables=table
```

I get the following error:

**EXP-00008: ORACLE error 904 encountered**

**ORA-00904: "POLTYP": invalid identifier**

**EXP-00000: Export terminated unsuccessfully**

I searched about it on the net and I understand that the problem is version incompatibility.

What do you advice me to do about it?

NOTE: I also tried to export with data pump but it gives:

```
UDE-00018: Data Pump client is incompatible with database version 10.2.0.4.0
```

Comment: I think it would be appropriate to ask to http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally speaking, Oracle export is not backward compatible with prior releases. You'll need to use the 10g export on the 10g database. Get the 10g client and install it with the database utilities option to get the exp/imp tools. On the flip side, Oracle imp is generally backward compatible with prior releases of exp.

Answer (score 0):

I use VERSION=10.2 from a 11g client